# Mobile site no longer displays duplicate links

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, mobile-web

A new feature was added recently which separates the "possible duplicate" messages from the question content itself, as well as adjusting other things with the duplicate voting. Excellent features, IMO.

However, the mobile site has apparently not been updated to show these messages, so viewing a post on mobile that has duplicate votes or is closed as a duplicate does not reveal any links to the dupe(s).

Here's an example:

[image: Sample Mobile View]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for finding this - it has been fixed.